# Bootstrap 4.x navbar dropdown at medium breakpoint, expanded at large breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4.1  I have built a navbar that collapses at when the screen is less than medium width, roughly like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap flex-fill minw-0">
        <a class="app-link navbar-brand text-truncate mr-auto mt-auto mb-auto" href="../"><img class="app-logo mt-auto mb-auto align-middle" src="applogo.svg">Test</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler my-auto ml-auto" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.sample3">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse sample3 flex-wrap d-md-inline-flex justify-content-end">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav flex-nowrap text-nowrap">
            <li class="active nav-item"><a class="nav-link icon-mmnu-home" href="../../../"><label>Home</label></a></li>            
            ...
            <li class="nav-item flex-fill">
                <div class="input-group flex-nowrap flex-fill">
                    <input class="nav-input form-control h-auto py-1 my-0" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" aria-label="Search" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    <button class="btn btn-success input-group-append py-1 my-0" type="button"><i class="icon-mmnu-search small"/></button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

To take a little less real-estate, I've changed the search component a drop down. Roughly like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap flex-fill minw-0">
        <a class="app-link navbar-brand text-truncate mr-auto mt-auto mb-auto" href="../"><img class="app-logo mt-auto mb-auto align-middle" src="applogo.svg">Test</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler my-auto ml-auto" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.sample3">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse sample3 flex-wrap d-md-inline-flex justify-content-end">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav flex-nowrap text-nowrap">
            <li class="active nav-item"><a class="nav-link icon-mmnu-home" href="../../../"><label>Home</label></a></li>            
            ...
            <li class="nav-item flex-fill dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link icon-mmnu-search dropdown-toggle" id="btnSearchDropDown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><label>Search</label></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right m-0 p-0" aria-labelledby="btnSearchDropDown">
                    <div class="input-group form-group flex-nowrap p-0 px-1 m-0">
                        <input class="nav-input form-control h-auto" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" aria-label="Search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-success input-group-append" type="button"><i class="icon-mmnu-search small"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Now what I want to do is make the search controls inline when the screen is large or greater, but when smaller than that, I want the search controls to behave as a dropdown.  When the entire navbar is collapsed, it would make sense to also display the search controls inline, without the dropdown.

Originally I thought that the behavior seemed to be a combination of what the collapse component and the dropdown component do, but collapse isn't a responsive component - it doesn't have any breakpoints.  Then I thought maybe I could use navbar-expand-* and collapse, but that means that I would essentially be nesting a navbar-expand inside a parent navbar-expand,  and I'm having trouble getting that working.  Does this seem possible?